# Save and Restore associations in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I have Rails application with MySQL database.In it I have a complex object A. It has many B objects, which has many C objects. I have form for edit A object. After edit I save changes and relations. My aim is to make history for object A. History need to see diff between edit sessions and for restore previous state of object A with all relations.

My question: is any gem like [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for audit object with relations? If no, is any principles for construct such functionality? Maybe good idea to realize it in database using trigger and procedures?

Answer (score 0):

VestalVersions is a gem that can be used to track changes to data objects.

There's a railscast available on this exact topic here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning

Comment: I find [Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) and VestalVersions to, and saw your link in PaperTrail readme, but there is no words about relations. In PaperTrail functionality for restore associations is not realized ([link](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/undo-and-redo-with-papertrail)). Unfortunately this is what I'm looking for.